# Can DB2 and SQL Server be installed on the same machine?

Tags: sql-server, db2

I suspect there should be no problem as those are separate pieces of software, but ideally I would like to have some 'official' confirmation or denial as it will be production environment.

I'm targeting newest versions of both databases.

I was not able to find any information in official channels, but maybe I was looking in the wrong places.

Information about individual successes of failures would also be useful.

Comment: Given the products are from two different vendors, who would you expect to give an "official" blessing to the combination?

Comment: Well, but statement that setup with other vendor's software installed is not supported can realistically be expected. As I am still unable to find one, I'm assuming it will work. As stakes are high I want to be extra sure.

Comment: _Why_ are you doing this?  Obviously, you probably can't read the database files of one in the other.  If you're expecting to use this for a production environment, please be aware that the two systems will steal resources from each other when under heavy load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two products can co-exist peacefully because:

1. There is no overlap in the default installation path for the 2 products;
2. They don't require the same TCP port number for servicing requests - DB2 listens on port 50000 while SQL Server listens on port 1433.

Your real worries should be about server load *during* production. 
Without knowing what your current usage is, the installation of another database server will at least impact resource contention and utilization (of CPU, memory, HDD etc).

Answer (score 1):

Offcourse.

If you can't find anything against, that might be your answer.